# How can I make the value retrieving from Firebase database as an variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am struggling with Firebase Database...

I wonder if I can make the value retrieving from Firebase database as an variable

for example :

Here's my structure :-

```
"Numbers" : {
"Group1" : {
  "A" : "12",
  "B" : "34",
  "C" : "56"
},
```

I know if I'd like to get the number 12, I can call this

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Numbers").child("Group1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

        if let snapDict = snap.value as? Dictionary <String, AnyObject>{

            let theNumber = snapDict["A"] as! String

            print (theNumber)  //then  I get 12
        }
    })
```

But what if I want to sum up all the numbers in my structure

I tried to do this :

```
var theNumber : Int = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Numbers").child("Group1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

    if let snapDict = snap.value as? Dictionary <String, AnyObject>{

        let Number = snapDict["A"] as! String
        let theNumber:Int = Int(Number)!
    }
})
```

if this works, the sum can be like `var(theNumber1) + var(theNubmer2) + var(theNumber3)`

But when I print theNumber I get nothing

I hope this question won't sound stupid to you guys 
any comments is appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:-

```
if let snapDict = snap.value as? Dictionary <String, AnyObject>{

        let theNumberA = snapDict["A"] as! Int
        let theNumberB = snapDict["B"] as! Int
        let theNumberC = snapDict["C"] as! Int

        print("The Sum is: \(theNumberA+theNumberB+theNumberC)")             
    }
```